# I can't access some of my databases in MySQL (I get: Unknown database '[my-database-name]')

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp, mysql-error-1049

I've been going insane with this, trying to figure out where I could possibly be going wrong.
I have this strange feeling it's some sort of permissions issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

I have just decided to move to MAMP, and I've moved all my database folders to the db/mysql folder, but they just aren't showing up for me in phpMyAdmin, nor can I connect to them via PHP. I get:

> 1049: Unknown database '[my-database-name]'

Trying to access them from Sequel Pro doesn't work either, they just don't show up.

- CHMODing them to 0777 doesn't do anything.
- CHWONing them to bruno:admin (my user and group) doesn't do anything.
- Creating a new database with phpMyAdmin works fine, and the database shows up and I can use it.

A sure-fire way around this is to go to Windows (wouldn't get permission issues there), export all the databases as SQL, then import them on my Mac. But that seems like such a stupid way to get around it. There's got to be a more intelligent way, and I want to understand WHY this is not working, I want to know what's wrong.

P.S. The oddest thing is, I didn't have these problems when I was using a regular MySQL installation, it's only now that I've moved databases over to MAMP's MySQL that this started happening.

Additional Information:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.10 sec)

mysql> show grants;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '[removed]' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: same problem! how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @gobo see my comment on the only answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to login to the db from console and try `show databases` or `show grants` to see if you have permissions.

Comment: The databases aren't even showing up in show databases, and I've got all privileges on all DBs.

Comment: I've appended the result of show grants to the question. I don't see them, I just see "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost' etc. etc.", so I assumed I had privileges on all databases.

Comment: Hmm.. that sounds really strange. I see you logged as root so you should see all the databases. You can also look in the information_schema database... but I doubt you'll find anything more there in this situation...

Comment: I ended up moving all the DB folders to my Windows, dumping them all as SQL files, moving them back to my Mac, and importing them all as new databases. That worked, but it's a crap solution (to phrase it better: It solves my problem, but does not answer my question).

Comment: As an even weirder thing... I can't find ANY folders on my Mac that have the same name as my databases. Where did they go to? They exist, and they're working, but I can't find them anywhere at all. *sigh* I miss the default MySQL.

Comment: I have this exact same problem on my Mac. Incredibly frustrating.